# Tkinter anti-aliasing on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, antialiasing

I used Python V3.9 and Tkinter V8.5 to create a dashboard, on a Mac mini running MacOS Big Sur.
I then ran the same code, with no changes, on a Raspberry Pi 4B, 8GB memory.
Python version is v3.7.3, Tkinter V8.6.

The code worked, but the RPi graphics shows aliasing not present in the Mac tests.
See attached screen shot- on the right is the RPi image, and on the left the Mac's.
Note the 3000 RPM mark, where the issue is clearly visible.
Note that text is not affected by this problem.
[image]

The version difference could be the problem, but (1) I think it is unlikely,
as the RPi Tkinter version is more recent, and (2) updating the RPi Python to V3.9 may be tricky.

So the question is, is there a Tkinter action I am missing that will enable anti-aliasing?
I searched around, but Tkinter documentation isn't abundant, and the most complete I
have found refers to V8.5. And Tkinter anti-aliasing issues I have found are not relevant (mostly text or too old to apply).

2020/11/24
I recreated the issue with the attached code. Also, replaced the the picture with the output of said code.
Thanks everyone for the comments!

```
from tkinter import *   # -------- graphics courtesy of Tkinter

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1024x600")
kanvas = Canvas(root, bg="black",
            width=1024, height=600)  # actual Newhaven screen size

while True:
    kanvas.delete('all')

    kanvas.create_arc(5, 5,     # binding box: x0, y0
                  300, 300,  # binding box: x1, y1
                  style='arc',
                  width=3,     # measured in the RADIAL direction
                  start=0,
                  extent=359,   # arc ranges from origin to measurement value
                  fill='green',
                  outline='green')

    kanvas.create_text(150,           # binding box: x0, y0
                   150,            # binding box: x1, y1
                   fill='white',    # white text
                   anchor='center',  # center anchor (default)
                   text=("Raspbian 10 (buster)      ABCQONM"))

    for yn in range (310, 600, 20):
        kanvas.create_line(5,310, 315, yn, width=3, fill='yellow')

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    kanvas.pack()
    root.update()
```

Comment: We'd have to know how that gauge was rendered to help with this. So we'd have to see the code. A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: There's no explict anti-aliasing controls in `tkinter` that I know of or have ever seen — so it's probably an artifact of the lower-levels of the implementation which obviously must be different on the various supported platforms.

Comment: Not sure if this does help here but as an information I'll comment it https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12380456

Comment: As stated, on Mac it seems like anti aliasing is enabled but it won't be for other platforms. Have you considered to use PIL to draw an antialias picture ?

Comment: @Atlas435 - The application is a dashboard for an engine (a bunch of round gauges) and it is ready, except for the aliasing glitch. I don't know whether PIL/Pillow will have the functionality needed...? Presently I am investigating PyQt5, but after digging for some 3 hours it doesn't seem promising. Thanks for the comment.